# Can I create name of router variable when calling router.push

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code, but unfortunately not working as aspected. What is the best approach to get it working? If I console.log(currentPath) it shows 'sales'. Which is good. But If I use it in `saveComponent` it shows the following error:

```
src/components/modals/CreateSales.vue:198:21
TS2322: Type 'string | symbol | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | symbol | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | symbol | undefined'.
    196 |           changed.value = false;
    197 |        
  > 198 |       router.push({ name: currentPath.value, params: { uid: '10'} });
        |                     ^^^^
    199 |
    200 |           });
    201 |       }
```

```js
const currentPath = computed(() => {
  return route.name
});

const saveComponent = () => {
    if (submitButton.value) {
    // Activate indicator
    submitButton.value.setAttribute("data-indicator", "on");

    store.dispatch(Actions.CREATE_SALE, form.value).then(() => {
      submitButton.value?.removeAttribute("data-indicator");
      changed.value = false;
     router.push({ name: currentPath.value, params: { uid: '10'} });
      });
  }
};
```

Route.vue

```
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/",
    redirect: "/dashboard",
    component: () => import("@/layout/Layout.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/dashboard",
        name: "dashboard",
        component: () => import("@/views/Dashboard.vue")
      },
      {
        path: "/sales",
        name: "sales",
        component: () => import("@/views/sales/Sales.vue"),
      },
{
        path: '/sales/:uid',
        component: () => import("@/views/sales/Sale.vue"),
        children: [
          {
            path: "general",
            name: "general",
            component: () => import("@/views/sales/sub/General.vue"),
            alias: ['']
          },
          {
            path: "relation",
            name: "relation",
            component: () => import("@/views/sales/sub/General.vue"), 
          },
          {
            path: "salelines",
            name: "salelines",
            component: () => import("@/views/sales/sub/General.vue"), 
          },
          {
            path: "invoices",
            name: "invoices",
            component: () => import("@/views/sales/sub/General.vue"), 
          },
          {
            path: "transactions",
            name: "transactions",
            component: () => import("@/views/sales/sub/General.vue"), 
          }
        ],
      },
   }
]
```

Comment: Could you please add the following?

1. Structure of the `store` component 
2. Definition of `computed` function

Answer (score 0):

You should get access to `.value` property in the computed property `currentPath` :

```
if(currentPath.value){
  router.push({ name: currentPath.value, params: { uid: '10'} });
}
```

Comment: I get the following error on `name:` which is; `Type 'RouteRecordName | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'RouteRecordName | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'RouteRecordName | undefined'.Vetur(2322)`

Comment: It is not redirecting, as value is proberly empty. If I console log it outside `const saveComponent` it shows `sales`

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: please share your routes config

Comment: Updated my post. I don't think it has anything to do with Routes. It looks like I can't access `currentPath.value` inside the `const saveComponent`.

Comment: Try out `return route.name || '/'`

Comment: Same issue: `Type 'string | symbol | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | symbol | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | symbol | undefined'`

Comment: If I change it to `const test = route.path` `router.push({ name: test })`, it doesn't give any errors, but I need the name. Looks likes there is a problem with name within the `router.push`

Comment: You should define another route that takes param like `path: "/sales/:uid",`

Comment: Boussadjra: I got that in my routes. The routes wasn't up-to-date. Just updated. It is not the problem.